# Interpretation of negative factor correlations?

Tags: correlation, interpretation, factor-analysis, factor-rotation

How would you interpret **negative correlations between factors** in factor analysis, and should they ever be negative?

I did FA with oblique rotation (**Oblimin**) on 30 variables which were intended to measure the same dimension, and I extracted 4 (correlated) factors. All the variables were previously recoded in order to express the same side of the measured dimension. Yet, some of factors have negative correlations that I don't know how to interpret.
Also, it may be important that some of the loadings from the pattern matrix were **negative** (which I also am not sure how to interpret). I would expect them all to be positive, since the items were recoded...

(Don't know if it matters, but I am using SPSS statistics, and the extraction method was maximum likelihood.)

I hope somebody more experienced in factor analysis can help me out.